Using electromagnetic force to induce insanity
I have an idea for a character that has absolute control over the electromagnetic force within the universe, and he can do this without any real limitation or worry about conservation of energy, making him very a mysterious entity since no one knows how he can do it, but an idea came to mind, would he able to cause someone to undergo Disorganized schizophrenia by simply sending electromagnetic radiation such as radio waves to a target's brain or would they just die before they could lose their mind

You have asked this yesterday and it got closed. Instead of deleting and reposting, which is way less smart than what you might think, edit the closed post to make it fit our standards if you want it reopened.

I'm not trying make spam and I'm not trying to be smart, I am trying ask a question so I can get an idea on how to do my character, but I was told it was too open ended and vague or something, then after editing so many times and being told it's not good enough, so I decided to overhaul it and word out as simple as possible and it was rejected because it "invalidated an answer" so I gave up and delete it so I can just this question that I made as simplified as possible and it's still good not enough and it's getting really frustrating so please help out how do you want me to write my question

Part of the problem is that you've done no research before asking on a service that requires research before asking. Searching on Google for "how electromagnetism damages the brain" goes a long way to answer your question, but the other half is "what is insanity?" The word "insanity" is like the word "color," it represents a vast array of mental health conditions. Which one are you shooting for? Sociopathy? Psychopathology? Vegetative state? Hallucinations and/or delusions? Various palsies? (*Continued*)

... And on top of that, what are the specifics of your electromagnetic super power? Are we talking simple magnetic fields or are we talking electromagnetic radiation? What field strengths? What wavelengths? There's so much missing background information that the question can only be answered with the phrase, "if you want it to, sure!" And that might not be an unreasonable answer. Super powers are just another form of magic. Trying to crowbar science into super powers is difficult in the best of times. If you're worried someone might judge your solution (*Continued*)

... bad because the affect on the brain isn't a "realistic" result of the super power, you've already lost the battle as that same person would judge you false for having any super power at all. Please keep in mind that our goal is to help you develop and consistently use rules of an imaginary world of your own creation - not to crowbar your fantasy into the Real World. If you insist on keeping this question, drop the worldbuilding and story aspects and simply ask on [biology.se] or [medicalsciences.se], "can electromagnetic exposure lead to insanity?" (*Continued*)

... And be prepared to explain what, specifically, you mean by "insanity."

@L.Dutch I've never been happy with the dichotomy between disallowing edits that invalidate answers and disallowing the resubmission of questions to circumvent that problem. Your own answer to my Meta post about this several years ago would suggest that you agree that asking anew is better than allowing the edit-answer cycle. My point is, we need to allow one or the other - which one would you prefer?

JBH yeah I guess that's a good point, it's just I have a bunch of characterization ideas and I know their not exactly realistic but I want them to at least be believable with some level explanation behind their powers having very specific questions that can't just be answered on Google, hence why I joined this after finding out about thinking it might actually be fun, but during this first I've been bombarded with people telling my question is and to edit it over and over again and being accused of spamming because of it and was restricted to asking one question a day, and now (*continued)

...I can't ask any questions for another couple of days and I can't even argue my case or anything, this site is feeling increasingly hostile and frustrating to the point where now I'm straight up scared to ask questions, which is a very bad sign on a site that's specifically for asking questions, at this point this site is feeling less like a place get help in world building and more just posting your story idea in the form of a question and have people critique it, frankly your comments are the most helpful and frankly most sympathetic I've had since joining and I genuinely appreciate that

I've voted to reopen in support of my answer to your Meta post about this issue.

JBH thanks buy I don't think that's necessary this was really just a question to start myself off with, like dipping my toes in the water, of course I bit plenty but I can see this isn't a very good question but I appreciate the sentiment however

Is this an official change of policy? It'd be nice to know, been twitching with cognitive dissonance every time a user posts a dupe - it'd be nice to know for certain. @L.Dutch

You could do way worse than induce insanity
"Absolute control". A dangerous thing to throw around when you're talking about a fundamental force.
If your Electromagneto wanted to kill someone, they could simply cause the electromagnetic field to change in magnitude between atoms in their opponent's body. One of two things would then happen:

If the field is weakened, then their atoms will not bond together as strongly. At a certain point, it becomes thermodynamically favorable for the atoms to just fall apart - the temperature is too high for their bonds to last long. In other words, the enemy would be atomized.

If the field is strengthened, then their atoms would bond much more strongly. This sounds like it would be counterproductive, but think about its implications: biochemical processes that rely very heavily on the breakup of certain molecules, like ATP, would stop working because it would suddenly require much more energy to break those bonds, and it would stop being thermodynamically favorable for that process to happen at room temperature. Quickly, the enemy's biochemical processes would shut down, including brain functions, and the opponent would fall to the ground, rendered an inert chunk of organic carbon-based molecules.

If the field is shut off entirely, then something even deadlier will happen. First, without any force binding them to their nuclei, the electrons will disappear from their atoms, resulting in the generation of an absolutely-massive electrical discharge as they suddenly fly off in all directions, leave the electromagnetic-nullification field, and then suddenly try to find a positive charge. This will probably destroy the opponent. Then, without electrostatic repulsion, all the nucleons in the target will start to fuse at room temperature due to the strong force becoming dominant over all others; additionally, they will just keep fusing because there's no EM force to make heavy fusion energetically-unfavorable. The nucleons would all join together into a single massive atom, which would have no forces opposing its decay.


For the record, I calculate that the Schwarzschild radius of the super-nucleon I mentioned in the last point actually is greater than its physical radius; in other words, Electromagneto could collapse you into a black hole and convert all your mass into energy (in what's known as a nuclear explosion). The mass-energy result of targeting a 70 kg human with the move "Ultra Electromagnetic Field Nullification Strike" is approximately $6.3\cdot10^{18}$ joules of energy, which is equivalent to around 1,500 million tons of TNT - more powerful than any nuclear bomb ever detonated.
But could you induce insanity?
Yeah, sure. Just screw with the electromagnetic fields in the chemical bonds in neurotransmitters in a target's brain. The electromagnetic field is something way more fundamental than I think you're giving it credit for. If you have control over the electromagnetic field, you essentially control all chemistry in the Universe, including brain chemistry.

Got a little off topic with the first portion of you're answer, but seeing how you're answer was interesting and satisfied my nerdy interests as well just straight awesome I'll allow it

Well, never knew electromagnetism control could do all of that. You learn something new everyday I suppose.

As written, your character has almost no limitations.  The power to control electromagnetism is on par with that of Superman or, perhaps obviously, Magneto.  Both are characters so powerful that they shake the foundations of disbelief.
From a writing perspective, I highly recommend reading Brandon Sanderson's blog post on his rules of magic.  In particular, his first law of magic:

Sanderson’s First Law of Magics: An author’s ability to solve conflict with magic is DIRECTLY PROPORTIONAL to how well the reader understands said magic.

It sounds like this is the real limiting factor for your character's abilities.
That being said, we have little to no information on whether particular EM activities like radio waves can cause any particular diagnosis, such as one out of the DSM V for schizophrenia.  There are ethics issues with such a study.
There is, however, some interesting prior at for this.  Koren's Helmet, aka the "God Helmet"," was an interesting contraption from the '80s which submitted the brain to a complex but weak magnetic field (on the order of 1 mT).  Its inventor claimed to have used it on thousands of people, most of whom described a "religious experience" such as "seeing God."  Whether seeing a religious figure counts as insanity is a very subjective question but it does show how the brain can be affected by magnetism.
.... mostly.  Attempts to replicate the results have not been successful.  Later researchers have not been able to get the extraordinary effects described.  However, for worldbuilding, this is fine.  Invoke Sanderson's first law.  If the effect is understandable enough that it takes scientists a decade to call the results into question, it is probably good enough science to convince readers to accept your premise in all but the hardest of science fiction.

Huh this is the first I'm hearing about this, what was the point of the experiments, to see if the notion "religious experiences" are just the result of electromagnetic signals to the brain or to see how it responds to electromagnetic signals, or was ultimately just for the sake of doing it, also that's very helpful information since the said design I have is a guy who serves God and claims he gave him his power and how you see is based on perspective either he's legit or just crazy and this notion of the "God helmet" might make how people see him a lot more mixed
